# Moen bathtub faucet is leaking

Tags: faucet

I replace the cartridge (1225) on my Moen bathtub faucet. It is still leaking. I removed the cartridge and noticed there were grooves in the valve body. I want to know if there is a fix without replacing the valve body.

Comment: It depends on leaking reason

Comment: How about some pictures of the problem area, maybe of the leaking.

Comment: Most of the parts on a Moen where a scratch would matter are protected by the valve which is plastic and can't scratch it.  Make sure you clear out any rubber gasket debris with 1225s.  I've seen a gasket somehow get jammed into the side hole to the cold water feed so just a little was poking out.  Pics are important with this type of question though.  Try to get them sharp and well lit and use a separate light if the camera flash causes glare.